# Will deleting payment info revoke purchases?

Tags: google-wallet, google-play-store

I used my credit card to buy an app for my son's nurvo Android through Google. Now I'm not too keen on having payment info stored on his account. But when I'm going to delete my credit card I get a note that "The following purchases will be affected".

Will deleting payment info also delete the purchase?

Comment: Unless there's a recurring charge or you try to get a refund I wouldn't expect there to be an issue.

Comment: Does this game allow in-game purchases?